# Does Dropwizard Support Servlet 3 Asynchronous Servlets?

Tags: jakarta-ee, servlets, dropwizard

Does Dropwizard support Servlet 3 asynchronous servlets? If not, is it on the roadmap at any time in the near future?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It uses Jetty 8, which supports Servlet 3.0. Jersey (and JAX-RS) doesn't have any support for this, but it's forthcoming in JAX-RS 2.0 (and Jersey 2.0). Dropwizard doesn't add anything special, but when Jersey 2.0 ships, the next major Dropwizard release will very likely include it.

Answer (score 3):

You can use https://github.com/jetty-project/jetty-eventsource-servlet. Read wiki for how to impl Servlet and EventSource

In your DW Service implementation you add your SSE servlet

```
environment.addServlet(new MySseEventSourceServlet(), "/sse");
```

Then add this to your DW config

```
http:
    connectorType: NONBLOCKING
```

now you can start listening for Server-sent Event's on

```
<host>:<port>/sse
```

ex.

```
curl localhost:8080/sse -H"Accept: text/event-stream"
```

See working example @ GitHub, https://github.com/andershedstrom/dropwizard-with-sse